# I am using golang present tool to build a presentation. is there a way to override the default templates?

Tags: go, go-present

the present tool uses default templates that includes google analytics code of talks.golang.org.

I would like to override/customise the templates.

I couldn't find examples/guides/tutorials to achieve this.

How to customise the templates ?

Answer (score 2):

do the following to override the default templates:

copy the templates folder from `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/present` folder to the project folder.

edit the templates: remove google analytics script in all the templates.

start the presentation with -base option: `present -base .`

with the `-base .` option present tool will use the templates in the current project folder.